# C insert into linked list from a text file

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I am trying to read the words from text file and add them into a linked list but i feel like my execution is wrong. Below is the code for inserting and reading the file.

```
Word *insert_at_back(Word *head, Word *new_word) {
if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_word;
    new_word->next = NULL;
}
else {
    while (head != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = new_word;
}
return head;
}


Word *read_word_list(const char *filename, Word *head) {

FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", filename);
    return head;
}
Word word;
fread(&word, sizeof(Word), 1, f);

while (!feof(f)) {
    if (word.string != 0) {
        Word *new_word = (Word *)malloc(sizeof(Word));
        if (new_word != NULL) {
            head = insert_at_back(head,new_word);
        }

    }
    fread(&word, sizeof(Word), 1, f);

}
fclose(f);
return head;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong?.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: The program just crash after running the below main code.

Comment: void main() {
 Word *head = NULL;
 head = read_word_list(FILENAME, head);
 Word *temp = head;
 printf("Hello!");
 printf("%s", temp->string);
}

Comment: What type is 'Word'?

Comment: typedef struct node_struct  //defining sturcture with reference to next node of same type
{
 char string[MAX_WORD];
 struct node_struct *next;
}Word;